# Does a char* when assigned a value terminates the String With a null?

Tags: c++

suppose i have in my code written following :-

```
char *abc = " Who cares";
int len= strlen(abc);
```

This provides me the length of abc . My Doubt is how does Strlen determines the length of 
abc here . Certainly it looks for null termination and returns the value . But that does that mean that abc is assigned Null at the place where i am initializing it with value " Who cares " ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `strlen` walks through the memory pointed to by `abc` until it finds a null termination character.

`abc` is not initialized with null.  The compiler places the string somewhere in memory (including an implicit null termination character); `abc` is then initialized with the address of the first character in the string.

So:

```
 0x1234                        0x123E  (example addresses)
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |W |h |o |  |c |a |r |e |s |\0|
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
 ^
 |
 |
abc = 0x1234
```

Comment: +1. The word 'null' is perhaps a little confusing. It's being used in two different ways. Saying "abc is not initialized with null" is perhaps a little unnecessary. The important this is that the compiler always puts in the terminating `\0` on string literals.

Comment: @Aaron: The OP asks "is abc assigned null", so I'm just responding to that direct question...

Comment: Thanks a lot Oli ...does that mean any String that we pass and stored somewhere in memory is has an inmlicit null character attached to it at last . If so Why do we get a junk values attached  in some rare scenarios where null termination is not identified .

Comment: @Ritesh: Any *string literal* (i.e. anywhere you've explicitly written `"stuff"`) will always have an implicit null terminator.  In other contexts, it is possible to lose the null terminator if you screw something up (e.g. if you accidentally overwrite it, or if you accidentally forget to copy it when copying a string).  In those cases, the string routines (`strlen`, `strcpy`, etc.) will just walk through memory until it finds the next byte that's equal to 0.

Comment: @Oli Thanks again ...that means in the first assignment statement we dont need to take care of \0 in case it is a direct String literal similar to "Who cares " above while for all other cases like strcpy and strcat we need to care of always terminating the char * abc by \0 .

Comment: @Ritesh: The standard string functions will automatically handle null terminators correctly, but in the example of `strcpy`, you have to make sure that the destination buffer is big enough to hold the entire string (including the null terminator).  If you don't, then `strcpy` will overwrite the bounds of the buffer, leading to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

```
char *abc = " Who cares";
```

declares a pointer `abd` to a string literal `"Who Cares"` located somewhere in read only(Implementation defined) location. Yes, it is NULL terminated.

Do not try to modify this string literal though because it will lead to an **Undefined Behavior**.

Also, in C++ the correct way to declare this is:

```
  const char *abc = " Who cares";
```